# How to merge data with duplicates using panda python

Tags: python-3.x

I have two dataframe below, I 'd like to merge them to get ID on df1. However, I find by using merge, I cannot get the ID if the names are more than one. df2 has unique name, df1 and df2 are different in rows and columns. My code below:

```
df1: Name Region 
0    P     Asia 
1    Q     Eur 
2    R    Africa 
3    S     NA 
4    R    Africa 
5    R    Africa 
6    S    NA  
df2: Name Id 
0    P   1234 
1    Q   1244 
2    R   1233
3    S   1111
```

code:

```
x= df1.assign(temp1 = df1.groupby ('Name').cumcount())
y= df2.assign(temp1 = df2.groupby ('Name').cumcount())
xy= x.merge(y, on=['Name',temp2],how = 'left').drop(columns = ['temp1'])
```

the output is:

```
df1: Name Region Id 
0    P     Asia  1234
1    Q     Eur   1244
2    R    Africa 1233
3    S     NA    1111
4    R    Africa  NAN
5    R    Africa  NAN
6    S    NA      NAN
```

How do I find all the id for these duplicate names?